# Acumatica: How to get current localization

Tags: asp.net, acumatica

I have another site will be called from acumatica. I want when i call a site, i will pass current localization via url.

As title, i want to get current localization after login.

Please help me.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a answer, i viewed a login.aspx.cs and i saw the cookie store culture.

Cookies["Locale"]["Culture"]

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check 
 PXLocalesProvider.GetCurrentLocale()
as one must avoid bypassing the framework.